# Can still cat/tail/head/etc. a file without the read permission

Tags: files, permissions, root

So as root, when I try to cat a file without the read permission, I can still see what's in it, which seems kind of strange, because as root I cannot write to a file without the w permission (it opens as read-only) and I cannot execute a file without the x permission.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
[root@aaaaaa enc]# ll logsuper
--w-------. 1 root root 3268 Apr 19 13:26 logsuper
[root@aaaaaa enc]# head logsuper
Done at Fri Apr 19 12:22:02 UTC 2019
```

Also can't execute file without the x permission as root:

```
[root@aaaaaa enc]# ll test1
----------. 1 root root 25 Apr 19 13:40 test1
[root@aaaaaa enc]# cat test1
#!/bin/bash

echo "${1}"
[root@aaaaaa enc]# ./test1 asdfasdasgasga
bash: ./test1: Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you tested the exit code of your commands with `echo $?`; also for `root`  the permission tests are bypassed: so `root` is, by definition, allowed to do anything. At last, learn about [*setuid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

Comment: Ordinary permissions do not apply to root. If an editor is saying the file is read only, root should be able to override it (with e.g. `:w!` in Vim).

Comment: `root` isn't restricted by the lack of `r` permissions.  It _can_ also write to files without `w`.

Comment: I see, but what about the x permission? I still can't execute a file without x even as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` can do anything and permission tests are bypassed for it.

Read also about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Since a program -even `head` or a shell, even when run by `root` (whose uid is 0 by definition)- uses system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...)

See also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).
Together they explain when [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) -done by the [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running  `/usr/bin/head` - will fail. BTW, [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) does not check permissions.

Notice that execution of some executable is done by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) which documents when it could fail. Your shell is doing many [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and `execve`  calls.

A good Unix programming book, such as the old [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), has several chapters explaining all that. Your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is just another program (read also about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)) and you could write a shell in C (or study the source code of existing free software shell programs, e.g. of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)).